# How to skip app build process while doing Firebase app distribution when the apk is already built

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, firebase-app-distribution

I have added a firebase distribution job in Gitlab. All it does is run the gradle task `appDistributionUploaRelease` . I have set the `apkPath` in there as well. So my build.gradle looks something like

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
    serviceCredentialsFile="<BLAH>"
    releaseNotesFile="<blah>"
    apkPath="PATH"
    testers="BLAH"
}
```

My gitlab file for the stage looks something like

```
build:
  stage: stage1
  script: 
     - blah blah blah
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build/outputs

app distribution:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - gradle appDistributionUploadRelease --info
```

In the above case, in the second job `app distribution` it runs the `assembleRelease` again. In the gradle land, the task might be dependent on each other and it causes this to happen. Is there a way to skip that if the build is already done. Its adding extra time to the build that I am trying to reduce. Thanks! Is there a way for me to pass on tasks across 2 jobs?

I am on gradle 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here -

You could work around this by using [fastlane](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/ios/distribute-fastlane) or configuring a shell script instead. You can also upload the APK or IPA directly onto the Firebase console manually.